# iOS: Present segue programmatically without loosing the navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm working in iOS app but I'm trying to present a tableview when I click a button in one of my scenes like it shows in the image bellow:

[image]

I tried this way:

```
- (IBAction)presentScene:(id)sender
{
 NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    NSString *viewControllerID = @"myScene";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];

    MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
    [self presentViewController:_categoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

But doesn't show the navigation to go back to the main table view or I can't even set the title of the tableview. Any of you knows how can present tableview?

Comment: If you want it to be in a Navigation controller (so you can press a back button) you need to also put "home" in a Navigation controller the same way you put the VC above it on the story board in a Nav controller

Comment: I want to navegation controller to show to go root uitableview

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:YOUR_DESTINATION_VIEW_CONTROLLER animated:YES];
```

Comment: Make shure your UIViewController var is not nil

Comment: ok I see your storyboard, add another navigationController before your view controller

Answer (score 0):

You should present the tableViewController with `UINavigationController` like so:

```
MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

**EDIT:**

You should add a `UINavigationController` in your storyboard like this:

[image]

If you do not want to show the navigationBar in your `HomeVC` then hide it:

```
// HomeVC.m
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Finally, push the `MyViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)presentScene:(id)sender {
    NSString *viewControllerID = @"myScene";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: controller animated:YES]
}
```

Comment: if I do it that way I'll loose my tab bar

Comment: OK, I think you need to add a `UINavigationController` in your storyboard. I will update my answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean

Comment: @Bannings it doesn't work. it doesn't do anything and my controller is not nil

Comment: @Bannings how did you create the animation ?

Comment: @user2924482 Check your `self.navigationController` and make sure it is not nil

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with everything I finally found what I was looking for:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: It seems not same with the problem that you describe